# Requirements in addition to path lifting between manifolds that imply covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

I am interested in what conditions can I add to path lifting that imply covering. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological manifolds, and $p:X\to Y$ be a continuous map for which path lifting holds.
Theorem 4.19 from [here](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/Foster.pdf) tells me that it is sufficient for $X$ to be a manifold, $Y$ to be Hausdorff, and $p$ to be a local homeomorphism.

In my particular case, I am happy with assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are manifolds embedded in Euclidean space (and are thus Hausdorff, I think?). However, I do not want to assume a priori that $p$ is a local homeomorphism.

<s>Given that both are manifolds, as I understand, a local homeomorphism will follow from both manifolds having the same dimensionality</s>. EDIT: As pointed out by JHF in the comments this is not true.

As I understand, path lifting in itself is not sufficient to imply the local homeomorphism as well. What if I assume that the path lifting is unique? Going by this response [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658143/covering-space-counter-example), unique path lifting is in general not sufficient either. But does the additional assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are manifolds help?
Could any additional structure on the manifolds or the map be useful (differentiability, smoothness etc.) to make the map a local homeomorphism and thus covering?

EDIT: The construction in answer at the above link (that provides a counter example for unique path lifting implying covering) relies on compositions of cover maps having path lifting, but not necessarily being covering maps themselves. However, going by Theorem 2.11 [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf), compositions of covering maps will be covers if my spaces are locally path connected and semi-locally simply connected. If my spaces are manifolds, I believe I have enough niceness properties that this type of counter example would not work.

EDIT: Without going into too many details, my problem has its origins in modeling something physical, so I can make more assumptions, but I'm not sure what kinds of assumptions I should be making. I have unique path lifting, so I'm happy assuming that. In my problem, I know $X$ and $Y$ are "nice" manifolds, but I don't know what sense of nice I need to think about.
I don't want to assume *a priori* that my manifolds have the same dimensionality, would prefer that to follow from some other assumptions.

Comment: Covering maps are exactly Serre fibrations (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Serre_fibration) with the unique path lifting property.

Comment: @N.Pullbacki: I'll be honest, I don't quite follow what a Serre fibration is from your link. Is there some simpler condition that could be sufficient in terms of properties on the manifolds? From what I can tell, all I'm reduced to finding is the conditions for which the dimensionalities of the manifolds become the same. Is there some constraint I can put on path lifting or on the manifolds that would imply this?

Comment: A (smooth) map between manifolds of the same dimension is not necessarily a local homeomorphism (consider critical points).

Comment: @JHF: I see. Does it help if I additionally assume smoothness of the manifolds as well? What are conditions I can place on the map or on the manifolds so as to make it a local homeomorphism and/or have the same dimensionality (and then imply covering)? Without going into too many details, my problem has its origins in modeling something physical, so I can make more assumptions, but I'm not sure what assumptions I should be making.

Comment: No, consider the projection of the unit circle (as a $1$-manifold) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto the $x$-axis.  Everything is smooth, but this map is not a local homeomorphism at $(1,0)$ or $(-1,0)$.

Comment: @JHF: Ah, I see. And, if my intuition is correct, path lifting does hold in the example you gave, but the map is not covering? So I really would need something much stronger to go from path lifting in manifolds to covering maps?

Comment: Actually, it seems to me that maybe path lifting holds here but not unique path lifting? If I have a path in [-1,1] that goes to an end and comes back, then there are two possible paths on the unit circle even if I specify the starting point

Comment: @SarthakC Path lifting doesn't hold: The image of the projection is $[-1, 1] \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ so you cannot lift any path that whose image isn't contained in $[-1, 1]$ (in general, surjectivity of $p$ is a "trivial" precondition). But yes, when you restrict your attention to that interval you get lifting but not unique lifting.

Comment: @SarthakC On another note, is "smoothness" a reasonable assumption? If I am seeing things correctly then your question has a relative easy affirmative answer if you assume $N$, $M$, and $p$ smooth.

Comment: On thinking some more about it, I might want to rescind the "relatively easy" part unless you are also willing to suppose that lifts of smooth paths are smooth :)

Comment: @BenSteffan: Yes, I meant restricted to [-1,1]. But, as you point out, unique path lifting does not hold, so it doesn't work as a counter example to what I'm looking for

Comment: @BenSteffan: I am absolutely happy with assuming $N$, $M$ and $p$ are smooth. If there is some result that gives me an affirmative answer in that setting, it definitely works for me. Regarding your next comment: I am actually fine with assuming that lifts of smooth paths are smooth too. 
Although, what would be needed for lifts of smooth paths to be smooth? Is smoothness of $M$, $N$ and $p$ not enough for that?

Comment: @SarthakC If you only have non-unique path lifting then lifts of a smooth path need not be smooth (think of the projection $M \times N \to M$). If $p$ is a smooth covering then this automatically holds, but I don't see how to deduce this directly from unique path lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt under the assumptions that

1. $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, and
2. $p\colon M \to N$ be a smooth map with the *unique smooth path lifting property:* Any smooth path $\gamma\colon I \to N$ lifts uniquely to a smooth path $\tilde{\gamma}\colon I \to M$ through $p$ with $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = \tilde{x} \in p^{-1}(\gamma(0))$ any choice of lift of starting point.

Moreover, we will assume without loss of generality that $N$ is connected and $M \neq \emptyset$.

For a start, notice that $p$ is surjective since the constant paths at every point in $N$ need to lift through it. Moreover, I claim it is a submersion: Let $m_0 \in M$ be any point and $n_0 = p(m_0)$ its image in $N$. Let $\gamma\colon I \to N$ be a smooth path with $\gamma(1 / 2) = n_0$. We obtain from this two paths $\gamma_1 = \bar{\gamma}|_{[0, 1 / 2]}$ and $\gamma_2 = \gamma|_{[1 / 2, 1]}$ (here $\bar{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(1 - t)$) starting at $n_0$ and therefore two unique smooth lifts $\tilde{\gamma}_1$, $\tilde{\gamma}_2$ to $M$ starting at $m_0$. The concatenation $\tilde{\gamma} = \bar{\tilde{\gamma}}_1 \ast \tilde{\gamma}_2$ is then a lift of $\gamma$ subject to $\tilde{\gamma}(1 / 2) = m_0$ (and smooth by the requirement that lifts of smooth paths be smooth), so since every $v \in T_{n_0} N$ is the velocity vector of such a path $\gamma$ through $n_0$ and $\gamma'(1 / 2) = (p \circ \tilde{\gamma})'(1 / 2) = d p(\tilde{\gamma}'(1 / 2))$, we conclude that $d p$ is surjective and therefore that $p$ is a submersion.

It then remains to show that $p$ is an immersion and therefore a local diffeomorphism which implies it is a covering map. But this is not difficult: Any point in the domain of a submersion is in the image of a smooth local section, so let $m \in M$ be arbitrary and $\sigma\colon U \to M$ be section defined on a connected open neighborhood $U \subseteq N$ of $p(m)$ such that $m \in \sigma(U)$. Assume that $p|_{\sigma(U)}$ is not injective and let $m_0, m_1 \in \sigma(U)$ be two distinct points with $p(m_0) = p(m_1)$. Moreover, pick a smooth path $\gamma\colon I \to \sigma(U)$ from $m_0$ to $m_1$. Then $p \circ \gamma$ is loop at $p(m_0)$, so $\sigma \circ p \circ \gamma$ is a loop in $\sigma(U)$, i.e. $\sigma \circ p \circ \gamma \neq \gamma$ are two *distinct* lifts of $p \circ \gamma$, contradicting unique path lifting.
Hence, $p$ is a locally injective submersion, i.e. a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: To make sure I understand the idea: Smoothness of the path lifting + uniqueness shows $dp$ is surjective and thus $p$ is a submersion. 
Then, you are using something like submersion theorem(?) to look at something that is locally like an inverse ($\sigma$), and then using unique path lifting to construct a counterexample to $p(m_0)=p(m_1)$, making $p$ injective.
I think I'm not following the very last part, and that's probably something trivial that I'm missing, but this is not my area of expertise --- is $dp$ surjective and $p$ locally injective enough for a local diffeomorphism?

Comment: @SarthakC Right. If $p\colon M \to N$ is a submersion then each point of $M$ is in the image of a map $\sigma\colon U \to M$ with $U \subseteq N$ open satisfying $p \circ \sigma = \mathrm{id}_U$, i.e. $\sigma$ is a local section to $p$ (c.f. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", Theorem 4.26).

Comment: @SarthakC For the last part, note by the rank theorem (ibid., Theorem 4.12) that a submersion $p$ is locally of the form $q\colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $q(x_1, \ldots, x_m) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ (where $m = \dim M$, $n = \dim N$) after composing with suitable charts, and this map is injective iff $m = n$ in which case $q = \mathbb{id}_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ is in particular a diffeomorphism, so $p$ is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: It would be injective iff $m\leq n$, right? Why is $m=n$? Because $m\geq n$ because $p:M\to N$ is a smooth map?

Comment: @SarthakC In general you're correct, but $m \geq n$ already follows from the fact that $p$ is a submersion (essentially by definition: a submersion is a map whose differential at every point is surjective, and there are no surjective linear maps $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ if $m < n$) :)

Comment: In the first part, why does one need to go through the trouble of constructing paths with $m_0$ and $n_0$ at 1/2? Why can't we just directly look at a path $\gamma$ starting at $n_0$, consider it's unique lift $\tilde \gamma$ starting at $m_0$ and say that $\gamma'(0) = (p\circ \tilde \gamma)'(0) = dp(\tilde\gamma'(0))$ and thus $dp$ is surjective?

Comment: @SarthakC There is on the nose an issue with differentiability at $0 \in [0, 1]$; I guess that's why the definition I know (and used) picks some point in the interior. However, I realized after writing this that really you can also do it at 0 since smoothness of the path is meant in the sense that there is a smooth extension to $(0 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$, so you're correct.